# Incorrect response to the REST call using node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, asynchronous

I have the following api :

```
for (var index in workload.elements) {
    (function(index) {
        var arr = [];
        var resourceIdentifiers = {};
        var elementinfo = {};
        var metadataModified = {};

        elementinfo = workload.elements[index];

        arr[index] = workload.elements[index].uri;

        if (workload.elements[index].parameters.imageUri) {
            arr.push(workload.elements[index].parameters.imageUri);
        }

        resourceIdentifiers = arr.join(',');

        console.log('uri' + resourceIdentifiers);

        mysql.elementlevelpricing(resourceIdentifiers, function(result) {

            elementlevelpricingSummary = result;

            metadataModified = workload.elements[index].metadata;

            metadataModified.pricingsummary = elementlevelpricingSummary;
            delete elementinfo.metadata;

            elementinfo.metadata = metadataModified;

            workloadinfo.elements = JSON.stringify(elementArray, null, 2);

            elementArray[index] = elementinfo;

            console.log(JSON.stringify(elementArray, null, 2));

            res.send(JSON.stringify(elementArray, null, 2));

        });

    })(index);
}
```

console.log prints the correct result , but the response to the REST call is incorrect and getting the result of only one the value getting into the loop.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using a function expression inside the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

First off, use a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of a for loop with IIFEs.

Second, an HTTP request only has one response. You can't send multiple requests with `res.send` firing off a few times. If you want all of the information, just aggregate the results of `JSON.stringify(elementArray, null, 2)` and send the final aggregated data with `res.send`.